# What's wrong in this insert sql?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I am trying to create an entity programmatically.

My code:

```
//my entity
use \Drupal\my_module\Entity\my_entity;

$entity = my_entity::create(
      [
          'label' => "token",
          'type' => "bundle",
          'uuid' => $uuid,
          'user_id' => $user->id(),
          'entity_type' => $node->getType(),
          'entity_id' => $node->id(),
          'value' => 10,
          'read' => false,
          'created' => time(),
          'changed' => time()
      ]
  )->save();
```

**However, on save, it gives me this sql error. What am I missing?**

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'read, created, changed) VALUES
>   ('bundle', '4a6ca0e3-89f0-46da-8889-c42a7f45ec4a'' at line 1: INSERT
>   INTO {my_table} (type, uuid, user_id, entity_type,
>   entity_id, value, read, created, changed) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =>
>   bundle [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =>
>   4a6ca0e3-89f0-46da-8889-c42a7f45ec4a [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 2
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => article [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 14
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 10 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1493818295 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =>
>   1493818295 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()
>   (line 770 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Comment: Content entity type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words
Maybe "read" should have quotes (``) around it in order for this to work. I am uncertain why this is not done automatically.

Comment: No, that's not the case. `read` is boolean type.

Comment: the word "read", not the value of it.

Comment: Tried with `'read' => 'false'` or `"read" => "false"` both doesn't work and same error thrown.

Comment: "\`read\`" => false

Comment: Same error, very strange.

Comment: try the same with value.
I'm just guessing here :) The answer of Smalution is much better since that is the way to properly store a node. But I don't really know what you're trying to do. Just trying to fix your sql error.

Comment: I agree that both read and value may be problematic custom entity field names. It doesn't look like Drupal surrounds the field names with backticks, so you may need to choose different field names for your custom entity.

Comment: Yes, using reserved works is currently not supported, you have to use different field names.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact one but You can check this example.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Hello world',
    'title' => 'Goodbye world'
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

[More Here](http://realityloop.com/blog/2015/10/08/programmatically-attach-files-node-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

!Ahhh. What a silly idea to get caught in the middle.

When I checked manually in `phpmyadmin` it says `read` is system reserved. Posting this answer as separate so that it will be clear enough for others. @Ruben deserves the point for that [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words):